# Efficient node.js core (C++ / JS) workflow, for providing issue pull requests?

Tags: node.js

I've encountered something in node.js that'd I'd like to submit a patch for. I've also located a Github issue in which somebody also complained about the same annoyance. The issue has been tagged saying that patches are welcome. So, I'd like to try to supply a patch.

But, what's the best way to do this? I've forked the main node repository, and I've located the spots in the C++ code that an adjustment could be made. Before I make these changes though, I am trying to figure out how to test these changes of mine. I've got the official node package installed globally. I'm on Windows. How can I test this modified version of node?

Comment: Start by reading the project's [contribution](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) [guidelines](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Contributing) -- there's even [step-by-step instructions](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Contributing-for-Dummies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, the `vcbuild.bat` produces project files that can simply be opened up with Visual Studio. So, code editing and debugging can all easily be done within VS. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You can install node-gyp to build the addon manually (`npm install node-gyp -g`). Then just change to the addon's root directory and simply do `node-gyp rebuild` after you make changes.